# How to use Global extension in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

On an Angular 12 application I created the following extension:

```
declare global {
  interface String {
    toNumber(): number | null;
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "toNumber", {
  value: function(this: string) {
    return Number(this) || null;
  }
});
```

When using in an Angular's component:

```
var number = stringValue.toNumber();
```

I get the error:

```
Property 'toNumber' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

What is the best way to use such extensions in Angular?

Do I need to change the way I am creating the extension?

Comment: I just quickly tested it in Stackbliz ==> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6z47pb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fextension.ts. But it looks to be working fine.

Comment: @Unknown Strange. In my app it only worked when using Amer Yousuf implementation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following:

- You need to define the signature of the extension method in the global interface. Either put it in a separate file, e.g. under the `src` folder create a `global.d.ts` file. Or add it to the file of the implementation of the method further below:

```js
declare global {
  interface String {
    toNumber(): number | null;
  }
}
export {}; // to define this file as a module
```

- Add the implementation of the extension method within file `string-extension.ts` anywhere under `src` folder, with the following content:

```js
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "toNumber", {
  value(this: string) {
    return Number(this) || null;
  }
});
export {}; // to define this file as a module
```

- Import the `string-extension.ts` file into `app.module.ts` to make the extension available globally:

```js
 import 'PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE/string-extension'
```